# A passed JSON Object is printed as a [Function] at the destination function

Tags: node.js, rest, express

I am fairly new to NodeJS and asynchronous programming. I've never been seriously into JavaScript until I started working on a project that required me to set up a REST API using node server and I started working on it for the past day or two. I'm trying to set up a modular application and have been successful in setting up a route, model and controller using Express JS.

I use express to read the request bodies to get data posted to the server in JSON. But my current situation came up when I tried to pass certain data from my routes module (or file) to my controller in a function call.

When I couldn't read the data I tried to log it and to my surprise the JSON Object that I passed as an argument is now logged as a [Function].

Here is how I pass the data:

routes.js

```
var express = require('express');

var UserCtrl = require('./controller');

var user = express.Router();

// Define routes

// Request to list all users.
user.get('/', function (req, res){
    UserCtrl.getAll(function (result){
        res.json(result);
    });
});

user.post('/create', function (req, res){
    var postData = {
        'firstName': req.body.firstName
    };
    UserCtrl.create(function (postData, result){
        res.json(result);
    });
});

module.exports = user;
```

controller.js

```
var Users = require('./model');

// list all users
module.exports.getAll = function (callback) {
    Users.findAll(callback);
}

// create user
module.exports.create = function (postData, callback) {
    console.log(postData);
    // create user by passing the user to a model
    Users.create (newUser, callback);
}
```

May be I've got the basics wrong or may be this is completely a mistake of my code. Should I make the controller also an express middleware?

Comment: `module.exports.create` exposes a method, called `create` that takes `postData` and a `callback`. However, when you are calling `create` from `routes.js` you are passing a function as a param which has 2 arguments namely `postData` and `result`. You need to brush up on async control flow or use promises and generators, i would suggest the later. Example - https://gist.github.com/swarajgiri/16202e32aa4d80d45c62
**Note**: You need to use something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser to get hold of form post inputs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code calls create. The first value sent to it is a function. This function that you send to create takes in a `postData` and a `result` value.

```
UserCtrl.create(function (postData, result){
    res.json(result);
});
```

This code is what is getting called. The first thing that gets sent in is postData. When you called it just above you sent in a function to that first thing. So console.log will output function.

```
module.exports.create = function (postData, callback) {
    console.log(postData);
    // create user by passing the user to a model
    Users.create (newUser, callback);
}
```

Perhaps you meant to send in that postData object first?

```
user.post('/create', function (req, res){
    var postData = {
        'firstName': req.body.firstName
    };
    // This is the changed line 
    UserCtrl.create(postData, function (postData, result){
        res.json(result);
    });
});
```